# Fetching EMail Based on From Address or Subject

Tags: c#, winforms, email

I can read the new mail from gmail,yahoo and hotmail in winform by following code using `TcpClient`. But i wants to fetch the mail which sent by particular person or which contains particular subject line .I have searched more articles but i dint found anything working correctly . can anyone tell me how to do that ?

```
 public string hotmail(string username, string password)
    {
        string result = "";
        string str = string.Empty;
        string strTemp = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            TcpClient tcpclient = new TcpClient();
            tcpclient.Connect("pop3.live.com", 995);
            System.Net.Security.SslStream sslstream = new SslStream(tcpclient.GetStream());
            sslstream.AuthenticateAsClient("pop3.live.com");
            System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sslstream);
            System.IO.StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(sslstream);
            strTemp = reader.ReadLine();
            sw.WriteLine("USER" + " " + username);
            sw.Flush();
            strTemp = reader.ReadLine();
            sw.WriteLine("PASS" + " " + password);
            sw.Flush();
            strTemp = reader.ReadLine();
            string[] numbers = Regex.Split(strTemp, @"\D+");
            int a = 0;
            foreach (string value in numbers)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                {

                    int i = int.Parse(value);
                    numbers[a] = i.ToString();
                    a++;
                }
            }
            sw.WriteLine("RETR" + " " + numbers[0]);
            sw.Flush();
            strTemp = reader.ReadLine();
            while ((strTemp = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (strTemp == ".")
                {
                    break;
                }
                if (strTemp.IndexOf("-ERR") != -1)
                {
                    break;
                }
                str += strTemp;
            }
            sw.WriteLine("Quit ");
            sw.Flush();
            result = str;
            return result;
         }
         Catch ( Exception ex)
         {}
         return result;
      }
```

thanks n advance ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @tray advice you have to retrieve messages and filter it based on from address or subject line as following :

```
public void check()
    {
        string sub;
        string result,from;
        int i = 1;
        do
        {
            ImapClient ic = new ImapClient("imap.mail.yahoo.com", "user@yahoo.com", "password", ImapClient.AuthMethods.Login, 993, true);
            ic.SelectMailbox("INBOX");
            int n = ic.GetMessageCount();

            MailMessage mail = ic.GetMessage(n - i);
            ic.Dispose();
            sub = mail.Subject;
            from = mail.From.ToString();
            result = mail.Raw;

            i++;
        } while (sub != "subject" || from == "person@example.com");
        string mailmsg = result;
    }
```

This takes time based on your message .
cheers ...

Comment: cool its working fine thanks :), but how about hotmail ? do u have any idea ? hotmail does not support imap ...

Answer (score 1):

POP3 doesn't allow to filter messages to retrive. If you want to filter messages before downloading, you should use IMAP4 protocol.

See RFCs for pop3: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1939.txt and for IMAP4: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501

Comment: So you should retrieve messages (all of them) and filter locally.

Comment: sorry , do u think is that better way ?

Comment: for imap with yahoo see this: http://help.yahoo.com/kb/index?page=content&y=PROD_MAIL_MOBILE&locale=en_US&id=SLN3361&pir=tlxulflibUkK2UvBaKDhkx4pO1vaLvJBBpHW